# Bash removes underscores from my filenames?

Tags: bash, amazon-s3

I'm trying to move files from one S3 bucket to another and put them into a folder structure by date.  Put simply all the files at the moment are going into one folder and that folder has over 500,000 files inside of and I now need to sort through all these files and put them into folders by month.

The file names are similar to:
"This_is_a_file_20150403.xml"

So I loop through all the files within an S3 bucket, tokensize and get the date.  I create a yearmonth variable ignoring the day and move them into another S3 bucket.  But the filename changes to:
"This is a file 20150403.xml"

So when I try to move it, AWS can't find the file.  Why has bash removed the underscores from the filename?  I tried temporarily storing the filename in tempFilename but it still had the underscores removed.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0

for filename in $(aws s3 ls s3://stagingbucket)
do
    echo $filename
    tempFilename=$filename
    (IFS='_'; for word in $filename;
    do
        echo $filename
        if [ "$count" -eq 2 ]; then
            yearmonth=${word:0:6}
            echo $tempFilename
            aws s3 cp s3://stagingbucket/$filename s3://archivebucket/$yearmonth/
        fi
        count=$((count + 1))

    done)
done
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's because of `IFS='_'` . What did you intend for it to do?

Comment: BTW -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: You also have a bunch of bugs related to missing quotes; see http://shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at what your code actually does.

```
echo $foo
```

1. String-splits `$foo`, breaking it into pieces based on characters in `IFS`
2. Evaluates each piece as a glob expression
3. Passes each result of those glob expressions to `echo` as a separate argument
4. `echo` then prints those arguments with spaces between them.

---

Instead, use:

```
echo "$foo"
```

...to keep your string together -- and, likewise, quote all your other expansions as well.

---

For much the same reasons (unintended glob expressions), `for word in $filename` is evil; don't do that.

```
IFS=_ read -a words <<<"$filename"
for word in "${words[@]}"; do
  echo "Processing $word"
done
```